# Amazon Book Search API using Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-ajax, amazon-web-services

How can amazon API be used to search a book using an ISBN number with asp.net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/AWSECommerceService.wsdl
Create a proxy using svcutil.exe for above given url
and then this is the Method to GetBookByISBN. AmazonBook is my cutom DTO you have to create you own.

```
public static AmazonBook GetBookByISBN(string ISBN)
    {
        WebConfigHelper wch = new WebConfigHelper("AWSSettings");
        AmazonBook book = null;
        string AWSAccessKeyId = wch["AccessKey"];
        string AssociateTag = wch["AssociateTag"];
        string AWSSecKey = wch["SecretKey"];

        BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
        binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;

        AWSECommerceServicePortTypeClient client = new AWSECommerceServicePortTypeClient(
            binding,
            new EndpointAddress("https://webservices.amazon.com/onca/soap?Service=AWSECommerceService"));

        // add authentication to the ECS client
        client.ChannelFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new AmazonSigningEndpointBehavior(AWSAccessKeyId, AWSSecKey));


        ItemSearchRequest request = new ItemSearchRequest();
        request.SearchIndex = "Books";
        request.Power = "ISBN:" + ISBN.Trim();
        request.ResponseGroup = new string[] { "Large" };
        request.Sort = "salesrank";

        ItemSearchRequest[] requests = new ItemSearchRequest[] { request };

        ItemSearch itemSearch = new ItemSearch();
        itemSearch.AWSAccessKeyId = AWSAccessKeyId;
        itemSearch.AssociateTag = AssociateTag;
        itemSearch.Request = requests;


        try
        {
            ItemSearchResponse response = client.ItemSearch(itemSearch);
            Items info = response.Items[0];
            if (info.Item != null)
            {
                Item[] items = info.Item;
                if (items.Length == 1)
                {
                    book = new AmazonBook(items[0]);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return book;


    }
```

Reagards,

Comment: this is a wcf service reference? i would be more interested in SOAP webservice.

Comment: Associate tag? I can see an access key but associate tag?

Comment: Associate Tag is something Amazon used to track a user is redirected to Amazon from a certain Amazon account.. more info can be found on https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=149729

Comment: btw service is in wsdl u can consume it as retro web service as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library [Nager.AmazonProductAdvertising](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nager.AmazonProductAdvertising) you can install it easy with nuget. The library also support .NET Standard 2.0

You can find here a [asp.net Website](https://github.com/tinohager/Nager.AmazonProductAdvertising/tree/master/Nager.AmazonProductAdvertising.Website) implementation example

```
PM> Install-Package Nager.AmazonProductAdvertising
```

Short example:

```
var authentication = new AmazonAuthentication();
authentication.AccessKey = "accesskey";
authentication.SecretKey = "secretkey";

var wrapper = new AmazonWrapper(authentication, AmazonEndpoint.US);
//The Lord of the Rings
var result = wrapper.Lookup("978-0261102385");
```